# laravel 5.6 passport first command

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

When I run this command:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

I get this error:

> There are no commands defined in the "passport" namespace.

Comment: So did you install passport package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Installation instructions for Passport on Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport)

By the looks of your error you haven't installed passport via composer yet.

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

After that you must migrate your database to create the new tables required by passport

```
php artisan migrate
```

Than run your passport installation,

```
php artisan passport:install
```

You then need to add `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` to your `App\User` model.

You must then modify your `AuthServiceProvider` to register the routes in order to issue access tokens. Add `Passport::routes` to the `boot` portion of the `AuthServiceProvider`.

The final step of the installation is to modify `config/auth.php` by changing the `driver` option to  `passport`.

Finally clear artisan's config and cache,

```
php artisan config:clear  
php artisan config:cache
```

Again, all of this is in the [Installation Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport), I'm just regurgitating it here for you.